# Excel vba for each visible cell in A row, insert value in H row ?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I insert value in the H row based on the visibility status of A row in excel using vba?

```
Dim rng As Range 
    Set rng = Range("A2", Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 
    For Each cell In rng 
         rng.value = "Something"
    Next cell
```

The code above will populate 'something' to A row, but I don't know how to map this to H row (where) I want it ? Anyone have any ideas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Row` property of each `cell` in your iteration to map to the correct row in column H

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2", Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each cell In rng
        Range("H" & cell.Row).Value = "Something"
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If its the same value for each row, you do not need a loop:

```
Sub NoLoop()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("H2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set r = r.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    r.Value = "whatever"
End Sub
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I used it to help provide an alternate answer to a question, I hope you don't mind. I prefer it to looping. +1