# Assigning only visible values

Tags: vba, excel

I have code like below and I want to assign values to specific cells but only visible.

```
Application.Workbooks(toimportfilename).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E9:E200").Value = Application.Workbooks(fromimportfilename).Worksheets("Sheet").Range("F9:F200").Value
```

I also tried but it does not work thanks in advance for any help.

```
Application.Workbooks(toimportfilename).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E9:E200").Value = Application.Workbooks(fromimportfilename).Worksheets("Sheet").Range("F9:F200").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
```

Comment: `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` instead of `.Range("E9:E200")`. If you specify the cells from E9 to E200, it has no effect of visibility.. and do you mean visibility of cells in source or destination?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? From your code I assume that the visibility concerns the target and not the source range, is this correct? What is supposed to happen with values for invisible cells?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28609977/1369473

Comment: For the first time only visible values were copied from Range("E9:E200") using copy/paste functions but it took too much time, and I want to assign only visible cells to cells in other window. I want to do this:

    'Selection.Copy
    'Windows(toimportfilename).Activate
    'Range("E9").Select
    'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

but using assigning

Answer (score 0):

if I didn't mess with the file names, the code below is one ideas to copy your cell (all or only visible)

```
Sub CopyValue()
 Dim wbFrom As Workbook, wbto As Workbook
 Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet

 Set wbFrom = Workbooks(fromimportfilename)
 Set wbto = Workbooks(toimportfilename)
 Set wsFrom = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set wsTo = wbto.Sheets("Sheet1")

'to copy all cells, visible and Hidden
wsTo.Range("E9:E200").Value = wbFrom.Range("F9:F200").Value

'to copy only the visible cells
Set rngVisible = wbFrom.Range("F9:F200").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
rngVisible.Copy Destination:=wsTo.Range("F9") 'I use F colum to show u the difference from the two paste method

End Sub
```